# Papirus icon theme is not fully applied

Tags: icons, themes

I'm running Ubuntu Mate 18.04.1 LTS.
Recently installed Papirus icon theme.
The problem is that not all the icons are changed.
[image]
As you can see, telegram and sublime icons stay unchanged, but chrome, terminal and others are from Papirus.
I've installed Papirus theme accoding to this guide: https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/install-papirus-icon-theme-on-linux/
**My question is**: how can I apply Papirus icons to all available apps?

Answer (score 0):

Papirus icon theme have icons for Telegram and Sublime. Most likely those apps are installed as snaps and the associated `.desktop` launchers have hard-coded paths for icons.

You can check whether the apps indeed are installed from snap packages by running

```
snap list
```

If that's the case, then you should find `.desktop` launchers for those apps in the `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/` directory. Copy the associated launchers to your `~/.local/share/applications/` directory and open with a text editor. Then change the `Icon=` line to `Icon=telegram` and so on.

Comment: it worked, but only for menu. Icons on the taskbar first stayed the same, but then turned into icons thet are unrelated at all.

Comment: @Tino Do you have a `StartWMClass=` line in the `.desktop` launcher file?